# PHP - best way to bring array up one level

Tags: php

I have this nested array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Adam Smith
                )

            [ef] => Array
                (
                    [rate] => 0
                    [superannuation] => 9.5
                    [pportable_lsl] => 0
                    [hours_per_day] => 0
                    [hours_per_week] => 0
                    [weeks_oer_year] => 0
                )

        )
 )
```

And I want to bring all the child elements to the top level element. For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [name] => Adam Smith
           [rate] => 0
           [superannuation] => 9.5
           [pportable_lsl] => 0
           [hours_per_day] => 0
           [hours_per_week] => 0
           [weeks_oer_year] => 0
        )
 )
```

What is the best way to achieve this using PHP built-in functions?

Comment: You will need to merge the sub-elements of the array into one array, and then assign the first element of the top level array to that array. Check `array_merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply merge your arrays.

This can be done with PHP's in built function: [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

**Working example:**

```
<?php
$ar1 = array("name" =>  'Adam Smith');
$ar2 = array('rate' => 0, 'superannuation' => 9.5, 'pportable_lsl' => 0, 'hours_per_day' => 0,
'hours_per_week' => 0, 'weeks_oer_year' =>  0);
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Oupput:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Adam Smith
    [rate] => 0
    [superannuation] => 9.5
    [pportable_lsl] => 0
    [hours_per_day] => 0
    [hours_per_week] => 0
    [weeks_oer_year] => 0
)
```

[See it live here](https://eval.in/462655)